# XMLHttpRequest SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT Naming Convention and Conflicts

Tags: c++, msxml, x509

Does anyone know how the client certificate lookup works with `XMLHttpRequest` from MSXML.

When calling the `setOption(SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, ...)`
I don't know the naming convention of the certificate's CN.

I have a certificate with a `CN="company sa"` and if I invoke it with;

```
setOption(SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\\My\\company");
```

everything is working correctly.  But will there be a conflict if I have another certificate that has a CN like `CN = "company_somethingelse"`?

Thanks

Comment: Is `company sa` the internal name of the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you specify should be the full name of the certificate.  There should be no naming conflict given your example.

A helpful resource:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/6/5/9657c01e-107f-409c-baac-7d249561629c/MSXML4SP_RelNote.htm

Specifically:

With MSXML 4.0, the client certificate can be installed in the local machine certificate store, whereas in the previous release the certificate was installed in the user's personal store. After the certificate has been installed, you can use the Certificates MMC snap-in to view the certificate. If you have multiple certificates installed, you can use the setOption method to specify the name of the certificate with a full path to the certificate.

const SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT = 3
http.setOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\My\my certificate"
The path specified refers to the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates.